# How to store multi-line text in firebase?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am fairly new to programming, and I just started learning react-native. I was thinking of creating an app where people can share ways to do a thing. Like, say I wanna ask how to drink water from a container, so the person answering can write in a multi-line TextInput and answer it like-

1. Lift the Container of water
2. Put its opening to your lips, which are open
3. Tilt it in such a manner so that the water comes in your mouth.
4. Drink the water

However, when I store it in firebase, it stores it like this-"1. Lift the Container of water 2. Put its opening to your lips, which are open 3. Tilt it in such a manner so that the water comes in your mouth. 4. Drink the water"

When I read it using queries, it gives me a single line string. Is there any way to store it multi-line? I want the steps to be shown line by line as it is really important to the styling of the App.

Comment: Text is stored in Firestore in the exact way you pass it to the API, and is also returned in that same way. So if there are line breaks in the text, they'll be stored and returned as is. The Firestore console does **not** show the line breaks, but they are still stored. If you're having a trouble getting line breaks, edit your question to show the [minimal complete/standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, as it's quite useful).